# Convert 2 strings into char array and compare them as characters

Tags: c#

I have two string variables called sln and csln and I want to convert them into char arrays and then compare the characters between them I used

```
        string value = sln;
        char[] X = value.ToCharArray();
        string valueY = csln;
        char[] Y = valueY.ToCharArray();
```

and for some reason which I dont understand why it does not work

to compare them i used

```
        if (X.SequenceEqual(Y))
        {
        }
```

but to check if this works the first one must work as-well,I must convert them into characters and I must compare each character of X with the respective of Y,to make a percentage to the similarity of those two arrays, help please

Comment: why not just compare the strings?

Comment: Why? Why not just a[n]==b[m]? Or simply a==b? Why?

Comment: Welcome to SO! C# is not C, you do not have to compare strings char by char. Use `sln==csln` or `string.Equals(sln, csln)`.

Comment: first of all I have to convert them to character array because I need to compare each character with the respective character of the other array, and I already know that the strings are of the same legth

Comment: @user3184013 But _why_ do you need to compare each char? If this is some kind of exercise, then say it. Generally, if you want to see whether to strings have the same content in C#, you just do `string1 == string2` (in your case: `if(sln == csln)`). `==` will compare the content.

Comment: @user3184013: you seem to be fixated on the char array. IN C# we compare strings mainly.

Comment: Its not an exercise but a challenge that I have to complete, mainly maybe but that doesn't mean that characters can not be compared

Comment: @user3184013 Of course it can be done. We're just asking because it seems like an odd way to compare strings in C#. Furthermore, could you elaborate on why your current code doesn't work? To me it seems like it should.

Comment: I used  int count = Math.Min(sln.Length, 10);

            while (sln == "" || sln.Length > 10) 
            {
                Console.Write("\n Invalid input please try again->");
                sln = Console.ReadLine();
            }
and the same for csln to check the length and make sure is the same and then I used the code I wrote above to make them character arrays but it doesn't seem to work and I don't know why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hint that will go a long way in .NET in general - strings are actually char[] underneath. So instead of converting strings to char arrays, just access them like they are an array to begin with (because they are).

Here's Jim's example modified to use this concept...

```
string valueX = "assdf";
string valueY = "assdf";

if (valueX.Length == valueY.Length)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ok, Array is same lenght ... lets check the content");

    for (int i = 0; i < valueX.Length; i++)
    {
        if (valueX[i] != valueY[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not the same array!");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array is not equal in lenght");
}
```

Also, the string.Equal can land you into trouble if you aren't specific as to how the comparison is done. Case sensitive, cultural sensitive? Read this for more info...

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c64xh8f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Since it sounds like you're searching for a LCS (Longest Common Substring) or Levenshtein distance algorithm, take a look at this...

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#C.23

Comment: I did that already, now I have to convert them to character array to compare them and make a Switch case to check the percentage of the similarity of those two array

Comment: So you're trying to write an LCS (longest common substring) or Levenshtein distance algorithm? http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Longest_common_substring#C.23

Comment: I haven't heard of those terms before but I think LCS sounds more apropriate

Comment: +1 especially for links to most reasonable problems (Levenshtein distance) that *may* match OP's undisclosed problem.

Answer (score 0):

As for example u could compare the array this way if u would like to check every individual char

```
string value = "assdf";
char[] X = value.ToCharArray();
string valueY = "assdf";
char[] Y = valueY.ToCharArray();

if (X.Count() == Y.Count())
{
    int arrayLenght = X.Count();
    Console.WriteLine("Ok, Array is same lenght ... lets check the content");

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLenght; i++)
    {
        if (X[i] != Y[i])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not the same array!");
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Array is not equal in lenght");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: After I convert them it always shows that X[0] is equal to Y[0] and the rest are not even if they are set to be equal from the start as in "assdf", "assdf"

Comment: What is the exact content of sln and csln ?

Comment: A string of 10 characters (which a user will set the content of the character) that need to be compared as character array with another string of the same length and then make a percentage to the similarity of those two arrays

Comment: "make a percentage to the similarity of those two arrays" u might want to add that to your question actually :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need count of characters that match both value and position in each string. So one can `Zip` to strings together and than count `Tuple`s of identical characters:

```
 var same = sln.Zip(csln, (c1,c2)=> Tuple.Create(c1,c2))
    .Where(t => t.Item1 == t.Item2)
    .Count();
 var percentage = 100.0 * same / sln.Count();
```

Note that to compute percentage you need to cast at least one element to `float`, otherwise you may get 0 for long strings with small number of matches (1 out of 200).

Comment: Note that one may consider this answer code-troll because exact restrictions on acceptable construct are not clear nor exact problem is described - same can easily be done with loop.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we tortured you long enough to discover what your task is I can give you possible answer.

There is no need at all to translate string to array of chars, as string by itself provides interface mimicking such array.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string a = Console.ReadLine();
    string b = Console.ReadLine();

    int max = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
    int min = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);

    // dividing integer by integer will return integer
    // therefore durign division you need to indicate need for floating point value
    // or just use float type, cheap trick, but it works just as well and makes code cleaner
    float c = 0;

    // for each character up to end of shorter string
    for (int i=0; i<min; i++)
    {
        // compare them
        if (a[i] == b[i])
        {
            // and if equal, increase counter
            c++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Similarity is {0:P}", c / max);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```